# How do you access the groups of match/matchAll like an array?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Here's what I would like to be able to do:

```js
function convertVersionToNumber(line) {
  const groups = line.matchAll(/^# ([0-9]).([0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9])\s*/g);

  return parseInt(groups[1] + groups[2] + groups[3]);
}

convertVersionToNumber("# 1.03.00")
```

This doesn't work because `groups` is an `IterableIterator<RegExpMatchArray>`, not an array. `Array.from` doesn't seem to turn it into an array of groups either. Is there an easy way (ideally something that can fit on a single line) that can convert `groups` into an array?

The API of that `IterableIterator<RegExpMatchArray>` is a little inconvenient, and I don't know how to skip the first element in a `for...of`. I mean, I do know how to use both of these, it just seems like it's going to add 4+ lines so I'd like to know if there is a more concise way.

I am using typescript, so if it has any syntactic sugar to do this, I'd be happy to use that.

Comment: Can you try wrapping the `line.matchAll` with `Array.from`

Comment: @zecuria I tried that before I asked the question actually. I don't know what that it is returning, but it doesn't seem to be returning it into an array.

Comment: @zecuria thank god for typescript. My IDE tells me it is returning `RegExpMatchArray[]`. But that can't be added together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** `matchAll` will return an Iterator object `Iterator [RegExp String Iterator]`

`result` will contain an Iterator and when you use the spread operator It will give you all matches. Since it contains only one match so It contains a single element only.

```
[ '# 1.03.00', '1', '03', '00', index: 0, input: '# 1.03.00', groups: undefined ]
```

Finally, we used a spread operator to get all value and wrap it in an array

```
[...result]
```

```js
function convertVersionToNumber(line) {
  const result = line.matchAll(/^# ([0-9]).([0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9])\s*/g);
  const groups = [...result][0];
  return parseInt(groups[1] + groups[2] + groups[3]);
}

console.log(convertVersionToNumber("# 1.03.00"));
```

Since you are using regex i.e `/^# ([0-9]).([0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9])\s*/`

[image]

**2)** If there are multiple matches then yon can spread results in an array and then use `for..of` to loop over matches

```js
function convertVersionToNumber(line) {
  const iterator = line.matchAll(/# ([0-9]).([0-9][0-9]).([0-9][0-9])\s*/g);
  const results = [...iterator];
  for (let arr of results) {
    const [match, g1, g2, g3] = arr;
    console.log(match, g1, g2, g3);
  }
}

convertVersionToNumber("# 1.03.00 # 1.03.00");
```

**Alternate solution:** You can also get the same result using simple match also

```js
function convertVersionToNumber(line) {
  const result = line.match(/\d/g);
  return +result.join("");
}

console.log(convertVersionToNumber("# 1.03.00"));
```

Comment: Why do I need the `[0]` of `[...result][0]`?

Comment: Because its an iterator, you have more than 1 inside the first.

Comment: @DanielKaplan You will get a single match that contains 3 groups

Comment: @HR01M8055 oh. How can you get more than one match?

Comment: @HR01M8055 nm, I've deduced that would depend on the string, like if it were `# 1.03.00 # 1.03.00` (and I didn't have that `^` in my regex).

Comment: @DanielKaplan You can use match since you're starting your regex with `^`. Ultimately It will always contain a single element

Comment: @DanielKaplan I've updated the result with a regex image. Have a look

Comment: @DanielKaplan I've updated the answer again, that includes what you are expecting if you have multiple matches.

Comment: Nitpick: there's no need to spread the iterator to an array before `for of` usage.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `.matchAll` in this concrete case. You simply want to match a string in a specific format and re-format it by only keeping the three captured substrings.

You may do it with `.replace`:

```js
function convertVersionToNumber(line) {
  return parseInt(line.replace(/^# (\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})[\s\S]*/, '$1$2$3'));
}
console.log( convertVersionToNumber("# 1.03.00") );
```

You may check if the string before replacing is equal to the new string if you need to check if there was a match at all.

Note you need to escape dots to match them as literal chars.

The `^# (\d)\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})[\s\S]*` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `#`  - space + `#`
- `(\d)` - Group 1: a digit
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\d{2})` - Group 2: two digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\d{2})` - Group 3: two digits
- `[\s\S]*` - the rest of the string (zero or more chars, as many as possible).

The `$1$2$3` replacement pattern is the concatenated Group 1, 2 and 3 values.

Comment: I like this solution a lot better, but I hope you don't mind if I continue to accept HR01M8055's, because technically, it answers the OP, even though yours provides more value and I'm going to use it instead. I had no idea the second arg of replace could refer to groups. I guess I just assumed it couldn't because it's a string instead of a regex.